# How can I delete a file whose name starts with "#"?

Tags: bash, shell, rm

There is a file `#A.py#` that appears to be a copy of the original `A.py` in the same directory - when I try `rm`, I get the following:

```
rm: missing operand
```

What does the `##` notation mean? How did this file appear?

Answer (score 1):

Add quotes around:

```
rm "#A.py#"
```

Without quotes it's interpreted as a beginning of the comment

Comment: Do you know how that file might have appeared?

Comment: @AlexanderWisowaty nope, some your app has created it.

Comment: It's probably Emacs autosave file.

Answer (score 1):

You could also escape the `#`:

```
$ touch \#rmme
$ ls|grep \#
#rmme
$ rm \#rmme
```

Answer (score 0):

Like mention in other answers by using quotes should work:

```
rm "#A.py#"
```

Also this:

```
rm \#A.py\#
```

To remove all:

```
rm \#*
```

And just in case check the option `--`

> The rm command supports the -- (two consecutive dashes) parameter as a delimiter that indicates the end of the options. This is useful when the name of a file or directory begins with a dash or hyphen. For example, the following removes a directory named -dir1

```
rm -- -filename
```